# Запятая не нужна?

Tags: запятые

> Всю свою жизнь(,) Лео говорит, что посадить желает не менее чем сотку деревьев.

Comment: В вопросе нет проблемы, он решается элементарно.  Такие запятые только в начальной школе можно поставить.

Comment: Лео, в этом случае согласен с Sharon. Как вы это собираетесь выделять интонацией для пояснения? Факультативность даже с близкого расстояния не видна. Не ставьте запятуб, этого делать совершенно не надо.

Comment: **Господи, ну когда же перестанут даваться ответы на весь тот мусор,  что приносит на этот сайт Лео!** 

Comment: @Слава Аплодирую и соболезную.

Comment: @Слава Сайт уже вообще вырубился, его молчаливость зашкаливает.

Comment: Участник, помни! Давая ответ на подобные вопросы, ты делаешь "мусорным" наш сайт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не вижу никаких причин ставить запятую. И ещё я бы сказал "не меньше сотни", зачем изощряться.